# Adding branch to a tree

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a class Tree

```
public class Tree
{
   private int tree_height;
   private int tree_width;
   private int nodes_count;
   private List<Node> tree_nodes;
}
```

I would like to create a method to add a branch to a tree
here is my code:

```
public void AddBranch(Tree branch, int node_num)
{
    if (nodes_count >= node_num && node_num > 0)
    {
        int last_el_ordering = nodes_count,
            first_parent_height = tree_nodes[node_num - 1].Height,
            first_parent_ordering = tree_nodes[node_num - 1].Ordering;
        tree_nodes.Add(new Node(branch.Tree_nodes.First().State, last_el_ordering + 1, first_parent_ordering, first_parent_height + 1));
        foreach (Node el in branch.Tree_nodes.Skip(1))
            tree_nodes.Add(new Node(el.State, el.Ordering + last_el_ordering, el.Parent + last_el_ordering, el.Height + first_parent_height));
        tree_nodes = tree_nodes.OrderBy(match => match.Height).ToList();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (Node el in tree_nodes)
        {
            List<Node> temp = tree_nodes.ToList().FindAll(match => match.Parent == el.Ordering).ToList();
            el.Ordering = i++;
            if (temp.Count() > 0)
                foreach (Node el2 in temp)
                    el2.Parent = el.Ordering;
        }
    }
}
```

the input

```
Tree testing_tree1 = new Tree(new Node("start"));
List<string> temp = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
foreach(string el in temp)
    testing_tree1.AddBranch(new Tree(new Node(el)),1);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   testing_tree1.AddBranch(new Tree(new Node("false")), i+2);
Tree testing_tree2 = new Tree(new Node("d"));
testing_tree2.AddBranch(new Tree(new Node("false")), 1);
testing_tree1.AddBranch(testing_tree2, 1);
testing_tree1.DisplayTree();
Console.Read();
```

the output (results)
the output
tree depth: 3 tree width: 4 nodes count: 9;

1. Node number:1, Node parent:-1, Node height:1, Node value:start;
2. Node number:2, Node parent:1, Node height:2, Node value:a;
3. Node number:3, Node parent:1, Node height:2, Node value:b;
4. Node number:4, Node parent:1, Node height:2, Node value:c;
5. Node number:5, Node parent:1, Node height:2, Node value:d;
6. Node number:6, Node parent:2, Node height:3, Node value:false;
7. Node number:7, Node parent:3, Node height:3, Node value:false;
8. Node number:8, Node parent:4, Node height:3, Node value:false;
9. Node number:9, Node parent:8, Node height:3, Node value:false;

> As you can see the last node has wrong parent, any clue?

Comment: This seems like something you would want to trace in your debugger.

Comment: You post what `DisplayTree` outputs, but don't show the code for `DisplayTree`.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Code looks way more complicate that simple `tree_nodes.Add(branch)`. Please clarify what you actually trying to do.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter The part
`foreach (Node el in tree_nodes)  
{  
List<Node> temp = tree_nodes.ToList().FindAll(match =>match.Parent == el.Ordering).ToList();  
el.Ordering = i++;  
if (temp.Count() > 0)  
foreach (Node el2 in temp)  
el2.Parent = el.Ordering;  `
in Add branch is not re-numbering the nodes correctly

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still having problems understanding what your goal is.  Are you trying to sort your nodes in the tree?  Also, does the class `Node` have `Node` children?  Your structure is unconventional so it's hard for me to follow.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter No, my Tree has a list of all nodes, root has parent=-1; and other nodes got parents
When i have a tree with 5 nodes (numbered 1 to 5) and i add new tree with 3 nodes (numbered 1 to 3) =>
i get new tree and i have to renumber the nodes in the order 1 to 8 and >>attach them<< to the corresponding parents, I am not able to figure out how to properly renumber and attach them.

Comment: This makes a little more sense as to what you're trying to do now, see my edited answer and let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your model of a tree isn't quite right.  For instance, your `Tree` class has no root, but only children, which is not a conventional way to make a tree.  It's also not clear from your question how your `Node` class is constructed either so I'm not sure if there's another issue there.

This is a pretty straight-forward way to get something close to what you want, so maybe this would be a good starting point (DISCLAIMER: not tested)

```
class Tree
{
    public class Node
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public Node Root { get; set; }

    public void AddBranch(Tree tree, int add_num)
    {
        Root.Children.Insert(add_num, tree.Root);
    }
}
```

EDIT: with your recent comment above, I'm understanding a little better now.  You're goal is to create a `Tree` class, which represents it's nodes linearly with a `List`.  Each node has an index to indicate which node in the list is it's parent.  There is an issue in your code with inserting an item by index into your list.  Your `Tree` should not bleed the `List` abstraction outside of the `Tree` class.  To everyone else, your tree is a tree, not a list.  When you add your branch, you need to determine the rules for how you want to add it.  As a leaf?  As the root and add the existing nodes as children?  It's unclear what your rules are when you insert a new Node.

Now to address the bug in your code aside from your (imo questionable) model.  By adding your (let's say `N`) nodes at an index into your nodes list, you displace all the indices of the objects in your Node list.  If you insert at index 5, then Nodes at indices `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`... move to indices `5+N`, `6+N`, `7+N`, `8+N`... and you need to address the following cases.

- Did any node have a reference to a parent node at or above my insertion index?  If so, in each of these nodes increase the index of it's parent by `N`.
- In each of my inserted nodes, increase the index of it's parent node by `5` (or the `node_num`) that you pass into your `AddBranch` method.

As for the rest of your code dealing with `tree_height` and `tree_width`... I'm not sure if there are any bugs without seeing your `Node` class.

Comment: my `Tree` class has List<Node> Tree_nodes which contains root at 0 and children of that root with attribute parent=1; etc.
    `public class Node{
        private object state;
        private int ordering;
        private int height;
        private int parent;}`

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to represent a tree with an array-like structure?  What does `node_num` indicate in your `AddBranch()` method? - **Even with these answers though, I'd recommend restarting your code to follow a more traditional model of a tree**.  It's just easier to understand and follow.  Easy = fewer mistakes

Comment: node_num is the number of node i want to attach the branch (1 for root)
i will try to rewrite the tree class... although i have decision_tree class too and i hope it won't get messy beyond my capabilities.  
Please could you give me idea to create recursive version of displaying the tree? (number of node and value, height of the node and number of parent in the tree)

Comment: by number of node do you mean the level in the tree?  Or the index in your Node list?

Comment: index in the list+1, root is numbered 1.

Comment: Best of luck, feel free to use the code in the post above as a template.